# USB install will not work with i386 or amd64 iso

Tags: installation, windows, 64-bit, wubi, acer

Having trouble installing ubuntu. I downloaded the 12.04.3 desktop i386 iso image, used the universal installer to put it on a USB drive (the netbook does not have a CD drive). netbook- acer aspire one with amd arm c-60 processor 1mhz with 4GB ram.

I changed the boot order to USB and I get:

**SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 2012-10-23 Copyright 1994-2012 H.Peter Anvin et al**

_ and cursor flashing but you cant write anything, no buttons work you have to do a hard shutdown to leave.

I tried the same procedure with the amd64 iso and get same results.

why did it not boot?

Comment: Ok, either you install using Wubi (**not recommended**) or using the bootable USB and install Ubuntu in its own partition. Check [How do I install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You have two good choices:

1. Create a Bootable USB stick with Ubuntu [[1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick),[2](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)]
2. Get a *Bootable External DVD drive* with USB Connector and use the Live DVD.